# No colour dots to tag folders. Macbook Pro, OSX 10.10.3

Tags: macos, folders, finder-tag

I have just recently bought a used Macbook Pro with Yosemite installed. So far everything seemed to work ok, except today I tried to tag a folder with the coloured dot and found it not possible. The dots are there, but they have no colour. This doesn't look right and I haven't seen anything like this before.
Has anyone encountered anything like that? I would greatly appreciate your help?

Please check the screenshot attached below.

[image: context menu of a random test folder]

Comment: Yep that's where it was - probably the Mac I am using came from abroad and had English named tags with no colours enabled, while the Polish coloured tags were disabled. Thank you again @klanomath :)

P.S. Italy was great :)

Comment: @klanomath can you open a chat with me please?

Comment: I try to please wait a moment. [Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22928/color-dots) it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the color tags have been disabled previously or some non-color tags are enabled instead. Just open Finder -> Preferences -> Tags and enable all color tags and all non-color tags you need.

Answer (score 0):

I can tag files, but when I click on a tag in the side bar, no files are shown.
This worked up until recently.  I did have to remove a bunch of Safari-related files to fix a problem with bookmarks; must have broken tags somehow.